# Is there something bad if someone is posting the same question on another website?

Tags: discussion, questions

Is there something bad if I post the same question on StackOverFlow and on another help/forum developing website at the same time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is fine. Just make an attempt to follow up in both areas.

You will probably want to tailor each to the community. Stack Overflow may require a question asked in a certain way to get results, whereas a mailing list with limited formatting may require another format.